# Optimising Z3 for rational fractions

Tags: z3

I am trying to solve a constraint problem with the following features:

- 4 variables representing real numbers
- a few inequalities by rational fractions which involve polynomials of small-ish degree (4), with an annoying OR.

I copy below the said constraints (note that OR).

I expect "UNSAT" (for N = 4 that's actually a theorem, but I'd like to go beyond 4!)

Unfortunately, z3 cannot solve this first problem. Any ideas or suggestions about tactics or other tools would be very appreciated!

```
[S_0 >= S_1,
 S_1 >= S_2,
 S_2 >= S_3,
 S_3 >= 0,
 Or((S_0/(S_0 + S_1))*(S_0/(S_0 + S_3))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_2)) +
    (S_0/(S_0 + S_2))*(S_0/(S_0 + S_3))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_1)) <
    (S_0/(S_0 + S_3))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_0))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_2)) +
    (S_1/(S_1 + S_2))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_3))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_0)),
    (S_0/(S_0 + S_3))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_0))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_2)) +
    (S_1/(S_1 + S_2))*(S_1/(S_1 + S_3))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_0)) <
    (S_0/(S_0 + S_3))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_0))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_1)) +
    (S_2/(S_2 + S_1))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_3))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_0)),
    (S_0/(S_0 + S_3))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_0))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_1)) +
    (S_2/(S_2 + S_1))*(S_2/(S_2 + S_3))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_0)) <
    (S_1/(S_1 + S_2))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_0))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_1)) +
    (S_2/(S_2 + S_1))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_0))*(S_3/(S_3 + S_2)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like z3 is choking on this problem, but both mathsat and cvc4 are doing just fine. Here's the problem coded in SMTLib:

```
$ cat a.smt2
(set-logic QF_NRA)
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun S_1 () Real)
(declare-fun S_0 () Real)
(declare-fun S_2 () Real)
(declare-fun S_3 () Real)
(assert (>= S_0 S_1))
(assert (>= S_1 S_2))
(assert (>= S_2 S_3))
(assert (>= S_3 0.0))
(assert (let ((a!1 (+ (* (/ S_0 (+ S_0 S_1)) (/ S_0 (+ S_0 S_3)) (/ S_1 (+ S_1 S_2)))
              (* (/ S_0 (+ S_0 S_2)) (/ S_0 (+ S_0 S_3)) (/ S_2 (+ S_2 S_1)))))
      (a!2 (+ (* (/ S_0 (+ S_0 S_3)) (/ S_1 (+ S_1 S_0)) (/ S_1 (+ S_1 S_2)))
              (* (/ S_1 (+ S_1 S_2)) (/ S_1 (+ S_1 S_3)) (/ S_3 (+ S_3 S_0)))))
      (a!3 (+ (* (/ S_0 (+ S_0 S_3)) (/ S_2 (+ S_2 S_0)) (/ S_2 (+ S_2 S_1)))
              (* (/ S_2 (+ S_2 S_1)) (/ S_2 (+ S_2 S_3)) (/ S_3 (+ S_3 S_0)))))
      (a!4 (+ (* (/ S_1 (+ S_1 S_2)) (/ S_3 (+ S_3 S_0)) (/ S_3 (+ S_3 S_1)))
              (* (/ S_2 (+ S_2 S_1)) (/ S_3 (+ S_3 S_0)) (/ S_3 (+ S_3 S_2))))))
  (or (< a!1 a!2) (< a!2 a!3) (< a!3 a!4))))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Mathsat:

```
$ mathsat a.smt2
sat
( (S_1 0)
  (S_0 (/ 3 2))
  (S_2 0)
  (S_3 0) )
```

CVC4:

```
$ cvc4 a.smt2
sat
(model
(define-fun S_1 () Real 0.0)
(define-fun S_0 () Real 1.0)
(define-fun S_2 () Real 0.0)
(define-fun S_3 () Real 0.0)
)
```

Both of these results are instantaneous. z3 seems to loop forever indeed.

I didn't check the models to be correct, so would be good to make sure they are OK and I got the SMTLib translation done right as well. You said you were expecting `unsat`, but obviously `mathsat` and `cvc4` both disagree, assuming the translation I got is ok.

If you find that cvc4 and mathsat are indeed correct, you might want to file this as a z3 issue as this is something they should be able to handle.

Comment: Thanks! Embarrassingly, the problem is that there was one typo in my constraints: the variables should be positive (not zero). In the two solutions found by Mathsat and CVC4, there are zeroes, which actually causes the rational fractions to go banana (infinite) since the denominator vanishes. Changing the constraint "S_3 >= 0" into "S_3 > 0" makes z3 much happier, and it answers unsat (after about 20s).

Comment: Note that SMTLib is a logic of total functions. That is, division by 0 is perfectly well defined. The solver can assign any value to the result of division by 0. This might sound surprising at first, but it's the right thing to do: Essentially, this ensures if you get an `unsat`, then it is `unsat` regardless of the interpretation of what division by 0 means; it's a common tactic in implementing partial functions in automated theorem provers like SMTLib tries to formalize.